# Linked error on combining to Wt examples

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors, wt

I am using C++ webframework for my project.
I am trying to add authentication to gitmodel example.

I am getting the following errors:

```
../hangman/CMakeFiles/hangman.wt.dir/Session.o: In function `Session::Session()':     /home/s/Downloads/wt-3.2.3/examples/hangman/Session.C:101: undefined reference to `void Wt::Dbo::Session::mapClass<User>(char const*)'
../hangman/CMakeFiles/hangman.wt.dir/Session.o: In function `Wt::Auth::Dbo::AuthInfo<User>::user() const': /home/s/Downloads/wt-3.2.3/src/Wt/Auth/Dbo/AuthInfo:94: undefined reference to `Wt::Dbo::ptr<User>::ptr(Wt::Dbo::ptr<User> const&)'
../hangman/CMakeFiles/hangman.wt.dir/Session.o: In function `Session::user() const': /home/s/Downloads/wt-3.2.3/examples/hangman/Session.C:138: undefined reference to `Wt::Dbo::ptr<User>::operator bool() const' 
/home/s/Downloads/wt-3.2.3/examples/hangman/Session.C:139: undefined reference to `User::User()'
/home/s/Downloads/wt-3.2.3/examples/hangman/Session.C:139: undefined reference to `Wt::Dbo::ptr<User> Wt::Dbo::Session::add<User>(User*)'
/home/s/Downloads/wt-3.2.3/examples/hangman/Session.C:139: undefined reference to `Wt::Dbo::ptr<User>::operator=(Wt::Dbo::ptr<User> const&)'
```

Full error list: http://pastie.org/5469803

I tried using the cmake generated makefile. After tracing down, it turns out that this linker error is after running link.txt under the CMakeFiles directory.
I tried to combine the link.txt for gitmodel example and hangman example because hangman does authentication too.
Here is my link.txt:

```
/usr/bin/c++   -O2 -g ../hangman/CMakeFiles/hangman.wt.dir/Session.o CMakeFiles/gitview.wt.dir/Git.o CMakeFiles/gitview.wt.dir/GitModel.o CMakeFiles/gitview.wt.dir/__/wt-homepage/SourceView.o CMakeFiles/gitview.wt.dir/GitView.o  -o gitview.wt -rdynamic -L/home/s/Downloads/wt-3.2.3/build/src/http -L/home/s/Downloads/wt-3.2.3/build/src -L/home/s/Downloads/wt-3.2.3/build/src/Wt/Dbo -L/home/s/Downloads/wt-3.2.3/build/src/Wt/Dbo/backend -lcrypt -L/usr/local/lib ../../src/http/libwthttp.so.3.2.3 ../../src/libwt.so.3.2.3 ../../src/Wt/Dbo/libwtdbo.so.3.2.3 ../../src/Wt/Dbo/backend/libwtdbosqlite3.so.3.2.3  /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so /usr/local/lib/libboost_random.so /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex.so /usr/local/lib/libboost_signals.so /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so -lz -lssl -lcrypto ../../src/Wt/Dbo/libwtdbo.so.3.2.3 /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options.so /usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time.so -lpthread -ldl -Wl,-rpath,/home/s/Downloads/wt-3.2.3/build/src/http:/home/s/Downloads/wt-3.2.3/build/src:/home/s/Downloads/wt-3.2.3/build/src/Wt/Dbo:/home/s/Downloads/wt-3.2.3/build/src/Wt/Dbo/backend:/usr/local/lib
```

Pastie link: http://pastie.org/5469815

Can anyone please tell what's wrong with my linking command?

On running cmake,
I get

```
/home/s/Downloads/wt-3.2.3/examples/gitmodel on master ✗ at  1:24PM 
➜ BOOST_FS_LIB=/usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so cmake . 
-- ** Not building gitmodel example: requires boost_filesystem library.
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

 should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
 if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
 information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/s/Downloads/wt-3.2.3/examples/gitmodel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like linker is not finding Dbo symbols.

If you're compiling with cmake, could you please provide your CMakelist.txt?

Looking at gitmodel Cmakelist and auth Cmakelist examples, it should be enough adding *wtdbo* and *wtdbosqlite3* to TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES.

```
user@debiam:~$ cat /usr/lib/Wt/examples/gitmodel/CMakeLists.txt
IF(NOT WIN32)

IF(BOOST_FS_LIB)
  WT_ADD_EXAMPLE(gitview.wt
    Git.C
    GitModel.C
    ../wt-homepage/SourceView.C
   GitView.C
 )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(gitview.wt ${BOOST_FS_LIB} ${BOOST_SIGNALS_LIB} ${BOOST_SYSTEM_LIB})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  ${WT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
)

ADD_DEPENDENCIES(gitview.wt wt ${EXAMPLES_CONNECTOR})

ELSE(BOOST_FS_LIB)

  MESSAGE(STATUS "** Not building gitmodel example: requires boost_filesystem library.")

ENDIF(BOOST_FS_LIB)

ELSE(NOT WIN32)

  MESSAGE(STATUS "** Not building gitmodel example: uses POSIX calls not available on win32")

ENDIF(NOT WIN32)
```

.

```
user@debiam:~$ cat /usr/lib/Wt/examples/feature/auth1/CMakeLists.txt
WT_ADD_EXAMPLE(auth1.wt 
        Auth1.C
    model/Session.C
    model/User.C
) 

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(auth1.wt wtdbo wtdbosqlite3 ${BOOST_SIGNALS_LIB} ${BOOST_SYSTEM_LIB})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${WT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
```

Comment: Added the cmake output in the question.

Comment: Also, looks like you installed your examples in /usr/lib ? How did you do that? any links would be highly appreciated. The documentation doesn't seem to work. Thanks.

Comment: Those are part of a debian installation. You can Check debian wt examples in package witty-examples: http://packages.debian.org/sid/witty-examples

Comment: Cmake is not finding boost-filesystem libraries. If you look in witty-examples debian package you can see that it depends on libboost-filesystem1.49.0. If you can install a virtual machine with debian-testing, for example, it would be easier for you to try. But you should learn to use cmake(not so difficult) if you plan to develop with wt.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't include User.C as a source file? Also You may have unintentionally left

```
DBO_EXTERN_TEMPLATES(User);
```

in your header file, without having anywhere the corresponding

```
DBO_INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATES(User);
```

Recommended resolution: delete all DBO_EXTERN_TEMPLATES(...) lines.